# How to use methods from another class in switch?

Tags: c#, .net, methods, switch-statement

I have a little problem. How can I call methods from class Person to the Switch-case in class Menu.
No matter what I do.
I appreciate your help.

CLASS MENU

---

```
static class Menu 
{

   public static void MainText()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1. Add new person");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Print all");
        Console.WriteLine("3. Find item by name");
        Console.WriteLine("4. Delete item by ID");
        Console.WriteLine("5. Exit");
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
    }

    public static void MainStart()
   {
       string choice = "";

       do
       {
           MainText();
           Console.WriteLine("Enter your choice: ");
           choice = Console.ReadLine();


           switch (choice)
           {
               case "1": 

                   break;


           }
       } while (choice != "5");
   }
}
```

CLASS PERSON

---

```
public class Person
{
    private int ID = 0;
    private string FirstName;
    private string LastName;
    private string PhoneNumber;
    Person p = new Person();
    List<Person> H = new List<Person>();

    public Person(string fName, string lName, string phoneNum)
    {
        FirstName = fName;
        LastName = lName;
        PhoneNumber = phoneNum;
    }
    public Person()
    {
    }

    public void PrintAll()
    {
        foreach (Person item in H)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("First name: {0}", FirstName);
            Console.WriteLine("Last name: {0}", LastName);
            Console.WriteLine("Phone number: {0}", PhoneNumber);
            Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}", ID);
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "First name: " + FirstName + "\n" + "Last name: " + LastName + "\n" + "Phone number: " + PhoneNumber + "\n" + "ID: " + ID + "\n";
    }

    public void AddPerson()
    {
        string fn = "";

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter first name: ");
            fn = Console.ReadLine();
            if (fn == "")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("First name can't be blank");
            }
        }
        while (fn == "");
        p.FirstName = fn;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter last name: ");
        p.LastName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter phone number: ");
        p.PhoneNumber = Console.ReadLine();
        p.ID++;

        H.Add(p);
    }

    public void FindPerson()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter first or last name: ");
        string search = Console.ReadLine();

        foreach (Person item in H)
        {
            if (search == item.FirstName || search == item.LastName)
            {
                p.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine("*****************");
            }
        }
    }

    public void DeletePerson()
    {
        H.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter an ID to delete: ");
        int id = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        H.RemoveAt(id);

        Console.WriteLine("Person deleted successfully");

    }
}
```

Comment: Your list shouldn't be on the person class, it should be else where (i.e Menu or a People class)(pref not a separate class just for this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Person pr = null;

    switch (choice)
       {
           case "1": 
               pr = new Person("FNAME", "LNAME", "012345678");
               pr.AddPerson();
               break;


       }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to declare methods 'static' if you're going to call them like "Person.AddPerson" rather than calling a method on an instance of the class that you've already created and assigned to some variable (such as 'thisPerson').

Comment: I don't think you should encourage to use statics, as this is something you want to avoid unless you have a very good reason. Which is not the case here.

Answer (score -1):

You have declared The class Menu as Static and Class Person as a normal Non Static class. It is not possible to call a non static class member inside a static class. If at all you want to do it , you need to make the methods inside the Person class also static. There is no other way using which you can can call non static methods inside static class.

Comment: Again: I don't think you should encourage to use statics, as this is something you want to avoid unless you have a very good reason. Which is not the case here

Comment: I very much agree to that.But It was an answer to the question posted and I agree to the fact that it should not be encouraged.